# Error org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [i]

Tags: hibernate, struts

I try to run below code but have error.

```
<body>
<%
    String uname = request.getParameter("name");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");

    Session s = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure() .buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    Query q = s.createQuery("from pack1.Login as l where l.name = :n and l.password = :pwd");
    q.setParameter("n", uname);
    q.setParameter("pwd", pwd);
    List<Login> records = q.list();

    if (records.size() > 0) {
        request.setAttribute("loginstatus", "Login Successful.");
        HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
        session1.setAttribute("username", uname);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/profile.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("loginstatus", "Username/Password do not match.");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SignIn.html").forward(request, response);
    }

    out.close();        
%>
</body>
```

File `Login.java`

```
    public class Login extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    SessionMap<String, String> hm;            

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Long mobile;
    private String password;


    public Long getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(Long mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String execute(){
       return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        hm = (SessionMap) map;        
    }

    public String logout(){
        hm.invalidate();
        return "success";
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
root cause

org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [n]
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:493)
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:118)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
```

Comment: `Action` is suffix. You should name this class is `LoginAction`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need `@Column` for each of the data columns in the class?  Unless you have an external mapping file, no attributes are mapped to the corresponding data column, and the class itself isn't marked with `@Entity`. So the original question notwithstanding, looks like you don't have the basic POJO defined for hibernate.